# processing returned json array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP page that returns a piece of HTML to set the values of a  menu.

```
while($employee = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $employee_menu = $employee_menu . '<option value="'.$employee['id'].'">'.$employee['first'].' '.$employee['last'].'</option>';
        }

        echo json_encode ($employee_menu);
```

Then update it with jquery like this:

```
$.get('http://www.sharingizcaring.com/schedule/menutest.php', { job: $('#job').val() },      
        function(data) 
        {

          $("#employee").html( data );

         });
```

For some reason the  closing tags are being turned into </option> and thus displaying as either:

First Last </option>
First Last >/option>

In the menu (Chrome) or as one line: First Last </option> First Last </option> (Firefox)

Is there something I need to do to the html besides json_encode before I pass it back or should I be returning an array and then creating the   with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you are json encoding the string you are sending to the client, just return the HTML string and update your element, i.e.: `echo $employee_menu;` and it should work fine.